# How to find out Top Stocks (Losers) for 1 week interval based on this data

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, sum

I have got Historical data with me and I am trying to find out top losers for 1 Day and 1 Week .

This is my table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `historical_data` (
  `symbol_name` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `current_day` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `open_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `high_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `low_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `close_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prevclose_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

INSERT INTO `historical_data` (`symbol_name`, `current_day`, `open_val`, `high_val`, `low_val`, `close_val`, `last_val`, `prevclose_val`) VALUES
    ('WOCKPHARMA', '2015-12-11', 1611.00, 1620.00, 1570.30, 1581.25, 1579.00, 1602.10),
    ('YESBANK', '2015-12-11', 709.00, 713.70, 672.25, 680.60, 683.45, 707.10),
    ('WOCKPHARMA', '2015-12-14', 1572.50, 1584.70, 1545.00, 1559.55, 1557.60, 1581.25),
    ('YESBANK', '2015-12-14', 679.10, 689.00, 668.00, 683.25, 683.65, 680.60),
    ('WOCKPHARMA', '2015-12-15', 1564.70, 1580.50, 1558.00, 1572.10, 1567.50, 1559.55),
    ('YESBANK', '2015-12-15', 688.00, 694.20, 675.75, 691.35, 688.25, 683.25),
    ('WOCKPHARMA', '2015-12-16', 1581.50, 1617.90, 1578.00, 1587.15, 1589.00, 1572.10),
    ('YESBANK', '2015-12-16', 697.00, 710.60, 694.25, 698.55, 699.15, 691.35),
    ('WOCKPHARMA', '2015-12-17', 1596.10, 1642.00, 1576.05, 1628.20, 1636.80, 1587.15),
    ('YESBANK', '2015-12-17', 708.00, 723.75, 705.70, 721.10, 720.00, 698.55),
    ('WOCKPHARMA', '2015-12-18', 1630.00, 1654.85, 1620.30, 1627.55, 1631.00, 1628.20),
    ('YESBANK', '2015-12-18', 717.90, 727.45, 713.60, 718.70, 720.20, 721.10);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48b83/1

And this is my query for getting top losers for 1 day:

```
select symbol_name , current_day , (close_val-prevclose_val) as toploosers   from  historical_data
where current_day = '2015-12-18'  order by toploosers asc
```

Similarly, I want to find out top losers for 1 Week also.

Could you please tell me how to find out top losers for 1 week?

I tried it with this query for 1 week , but I am not getting expected result

```
select symbol_name , current_day , (close_val-prevclose_val) as toploosers   from  historical_data
where current_day > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)  order by toploosers asc
```

Comment: `WEEK(current_day) = 50` -- or, faster `WHERE current_day BETWEEN '2015-12-13' AND '2015-12-20';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT symbol_name, SUM(close_val-prevclose_val) AS toploosers   
FROM  historical_data
WHERE current_day BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2015-12-18', INTERVAL 6 DAY) AND '2015-12-18' 
GROUP BY symbol_name
ORDER BY toploosers ASC;
```

Check this [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48b83/4):

**::OUTPUT::**

```
| symbol_name | toploosers |
|-------------|------------|
|     YESBANK |       38.1 |
|  WOCKPHARMA |       46.3 |
```

**OR**

```
SELECT symbol_name, 
         SUM(close_val-prevclose_val) AS toploosers, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN current_day = DATE_SUB('2015-12-18', INTERVAL 6 DAY) THEN close_val ELSE 0 END) AS PreviousCloseValue, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN current_day = '2015-12-18' THEN close_val ELSE 0 END) AS CurrentCloseValue
FROM  historical_data
WHERE current_day BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2015-12-18', INTERVAL 6 DAY) AND '2015-12-18' 
GROUP BY symbol_name
ORDER BY toploosers ASC;
```

Comment: If you dont mind , is it possible to fetch 6 DAYs back close price and today's close price  also  within the above result ??

Comment: Thank you , but why PreviousCloseValue is coming as 0.00

Comment: @PreethiJain Because there is no data for 2015-12-12 date in your table.

Comment: okay 2015-12-12 falls on satuday (market holiday) , so is it possible to display for the  previous day in case its not there .

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
select symbol_name , current_day , (close_val-prevclose_val) as toploosers 
from historical_data 
where week(current_day) = week('2015-12-18') order by toploosers asc
```